# Blender render turns into TV static on Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering

Blender render turns into TV static on Blender 2.8

[image]

This is the result when i tried to copy it into the object that I made with 2.7 before installing the new version.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please tell us more about your problem, or we can't help you. Are you talking about the artifacts?

Comment: hello, so as it shown in the picture thath there's a kinda bug on the edges like an unclear tv.But when i tried to copy it in my another viewport from the object that i've made with blender 2.7 it worked well. so can you please tell me what should i do?